# Optimize a GIF with PHP

Tags: php, optimization, gif

I have a script for capture a video with your webcam, and convert this video to a .gif.

I have this script for resize and save the file with PHP in .gif :

```
$image = new Imagick();
$decoded = base64_decode($gif);
$image->readimageblob($decoded);
$image = $image->coalesceImages();

foreach ($image as $frame) {
    $frame->cropImage($w, $h, $x, $y);
    $frame->thumbnailImage(117, 135);
    $frame->setImagePage(117, 135, 0, 0);
}

$image_name = uniqid(rand()).'.gif';
$image = $image->deconstructImages();
$image->writeImages('uploads/profiles/'.$image_name, true);

return $image_name;
```

So, with this script, i retrieve .gif with a sizez of 400-500ko, i think it's very big for a simply gif of 117px/135px...

How can i optimize this gif for reduce the size ? Thanks !

Comment: You could leave out frames (reduce the framerate) or you could reduce the number of colors.

Comment: A gif has a fixed palette and quality. Only option would be to reduce frames.

Comment: Can i do that with PHP ? Imagick ?

Answer (score 1):

It's very large because it is an animated GIF, which has multiple frames. One option is to use [`Imagick::optimizeImageLayers()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.optimizeimagelayers.php) to optimize the layers of the image.

Here's an example (from PHP documentation):

```
<?php

/* create new imagick object */
$im = new Imagick("test.gif");

/* optimize the image layers */
$im->optimizeImageLayers();

/* write the image back */
$im->writeImages("test_optimized.gif", true);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can skip some frames to make it smaller

```
// Use every other frame only
foreach ($image as $k => $frame) {
    if ($k%2) { // Use last frame if odd
        $frame = $lastFrame;
    } else {
        $frame->cropImage($w, $h, $x, $y);
        $frame->thumbnailImage(117, 135);
        $frame->setImagePage(117, 135, 0, 0);
    }
    $lastFrame = $frame;
}
```

Comment: Updated. I'll admit right now, that I haven't used imagick before haha.

Comment: Hum... the gif now is just disguting ^^ thank you anyway

Comment: just a note, video -> gif are usually quite big. The GIFs with small filesize that you see contain only a handful of frames.

Answer (score -2):

you can use ob_gzhandler in php

for more detail look this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

or

this sample maybe help you

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/how-to-compress-cssjavascript-files-with-php/

if none did not help ,you can use system function and use terminal or command line command

for compress you result file with os commands

be successfull